# Почему llvm-build не видит новый бэкенд?

Tags: компиляция, компилятор, cmake, llvm

Пишу бэкенд для LLVM, допустим он называется Abc. Скопировал директорию `llvm/lib/Target/AVR` в `llvm/lib/Target/Abc`, `bash`- и `sed`-скриптами заменил в названиях файлов и в самих файлах `AVR` на `Abc`, `avr` на `abc`. `CMakeLists.txt` выглядит так:

```
set(LLVM_TARGET_DEFINITIONS Abc.td)

tablegen(LLVM AbcGenRegisterInfo.inc -gen-register-info)
tablegen(LLVM AbcGenInstrInfo.inc -gen-instr-info)
tablegen(LLVM AbcGenCallingConv.inc -gen-callingconv)
tablegen(LLVM AbcGenSubtargetInfo.inc -gen-subtarget)
add_public_tablegen_target(AbcCommonTableGen)

add_llvm_target(AbcCodeGen
   AbcInstrInfo.cpp
   AbcRegisterInfo.cpp
   AbcTargetMachine.cpp
   AbcTargetObjectFile.cpp
)

add_dependencies(LLVMAbcCodeGen intrinsincs_gen)

add_subdirectory(MCTargetDesc)
add_subdirectory(TargetInfo)
```

Если в `llvm/CMakeLists.txt` добавляю `Abc` в `LLVM_ALL_TARGETS`, пишет следующее:

```
llvm-build: error: invalid target to enable: 'Abc' not in project
```

Если убрать `Abc` из `LLVM_ALL_TARGETS` и собрать с ключом `-DLLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=Abc` — та же ошибка. Что ещё нужно отредактировать, чтобы `llvm-build` "увидел" мой бэкенд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было добавить `Abc` не только в `llvm/CMakeLists.txt`, но ещё в `llvm/lib/Target/LLVMBuild.txt`